# facebook localization and access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, localization

I am having an issue with trying to use localization for one of our clients Facebook page. I have read the documentation and can confirm that the said page is available for translation (tried in browser). After spending some time, I fired two requests using 'Graph API Explorer' to the same page with only differentiation being access_token.

Request: (Using Graph Explorer API)
v2.3/*PageName*/posts/?locale=ll_CC&access_token=*personal-access-token*

Response:
Success with message field translated in ll_CC

Request: (from python shell)
v2.3/*PageName*/posts/?locale=ll_CC&access_token=*app-access-token*

Response: 
Success but message field wasn’t translated to ll_CC but was in the default (original) language

Question:
Does Facebook localization feature has restrictions on access token? 
If so, how can I update my app access token so that I can use localization feature?

Thanks for your help.

Best,
Nish

Comment: It should be locale and not local

Comment: typo. the request is locale. i will edit here. thanks